# Проблема отображения блока в Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, кроссбраузерность

Здравствуйте, друзья! Помогите с небольшой проблемой. Криво отображается блок в Firefox. Хотя в Chrome все нормально.

[image: Firefox]

[image: Chrome]

```css
.mail-delivery {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: right;
  width: 560px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-weight: 400px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: url("../img/message-pattern.png") #fff;
}

.message-wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 549px;
  padding:5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: #f8f7f4;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.message-wrapper p {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 22px;

}

.message-wrapper form {
  font-size: 0px;
}

.message-wrapper input[type="email"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 346px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  color: #323232;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #d3d3d2;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.message-wrapper input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px 21px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: left;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #e94e37;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f26843 0%, #e74b36 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(172, 16, 0, 0.64);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mail-delivery clearfix">
  <div class="message-wrapper">
    <p>
      Подпишитесь на нашу сладкую рассылку и будете всегда в курсе всего самого вкусного, что у нас происходит. Обещаем не спамить и не слать всякой не нужной ерунды. Честно =)
    </p>
    <form class="message-delivery" action="url" method="get">
      <input class="form-field" id="mail" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Электронная почта" required>
      <label class="login-form__label" for="mail">Электронная почта</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего не влезает кнопка - попробуй уменьшить её хотя бы на 1рх (можно так padding:10px 20px;). Можно уменьшить input.

Comment: Спасибо, проблема в кнопке это да. Но чтобы она в firefox отображалось как на макете паддинг нужно уменьшить до 14px. Пробовал уменьшать input. В firefox нормально, но в chrome уже идут несостыковки с макетом.  Мб есть еще способы, именно для firefox?

Comment: .message-wrapper input[type="email"] {
  width: 345px;}

Comment: Спасибо. Пока уменьшил ширину input'a, попробую еще поискать решение проблемы данной, если не найду это единственное решение на этот случай.

Comment: там скорее всего проблема при вычислении ширины инпутов при масштабировании. для проверки попробуйте при ваших старых правилах приблизить/удалить экран. Если на некоторых масштабах будет нормально, то лучше так и сделать...

Comment: при масштабировании ничего не меняется, как было криво в firefox так и остается при любом масштабе!

Comment: попробуйте для проверки убрать box-shadow, возможно он по разному воспринимается браузерами при вычислении размеров блока

Comment: попробовал. Он оказался не при чем.